# how to use `useQuery` to trigger api call only when onClick happens?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

how can I use `useQuery` to trigger some api call only when onClick happens?
I have an application that need to trigger api call, `useAPICall` with query data only when clicking button and function `onCheckingData` is true. Other than using `useState` to save the state if it is needed to trigger api call. or any better way for me to use `useQuery` inside useCallBack?

```
function useAPICall(data, shouldRunQuery=false) => {
  const query = useQuery(
    [{query: apiGQL, variables: {...data}}],
    async () => {
      const response: {data} = await ucFetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: apiUrl,
          variables: {...data},
        }),
      });
      return response;
    },
    {enabled: shouldRunQuery}
  );
  return query;
}

function onCheckingData(data){
  //do some logic checkign on data
  // return boolean
  return true
}

export default function App() {
  const [shouldRunQuery, setShouldRunQuery] = useState(false)
  const onClickHandler = useCallBack((data)=>{
    setShouldRunQuery(onCheckingData(data))
  }, [data])

  const {response} = useAPICall(data, shouldRunQuery)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>run query</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState({})
const onClickHandler = useCallBack((data)=>{
  if (onCheckingData(data)) {
    const { response } = useAPICall(data)
    setResponse(response)
  }
}, [data])
```

Comment: no `useAPICall` as use `useQuery` is still under `useCallBack`